# Protractor locators for a Kendo grid

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to click on this input field 
[image: the image shows the HTML file]

Comment: by.css("[data-role='filtercell']>span>span>input") try this

Comment: The input is *invisible*. Are you sure you want to click this element? Could it be that you need to do something else on the page to make the input visible?